# Proper way to re-initialize swift Realm DB on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I need to re-initialize local Realm DB on the logout in our iOS application, following:

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#deleting-realm-files

We use swift on iOS.

First of all, the fragment seems to be outdated, since the location of log files in now under 'default.realm.management'.

But most importantly, after deleting Realm files, if I try to access realm API without application restart again, I receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

The application works fine upon the restart.

Comment: Would the `Realm.deleteAll()` API suffice for your purposes? When you try accessing the Realm API after you delete the files, what methods are you calling -- are you creating a new Realm and seeing crashes even though you never reference the now-deleted Realm or any of its objects?

Comment: Yes. The application always creates a new Realm object, when accessing data. We never reference Realm objects that were created prior to deleting the files.

Comment: I asked our engineers what the recommended way to handle your situation is, and I've posted an answer. I'll also update the documentation, thanks for bringing the discrepancy to our attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting Realm files on-disk and continuing to use Realm is not something Realm supports well, if at all. Realms and their supporting objects and resources may not yet be deinitialized and cleaned up, even at a point in time when it seems to the app as if all references to the old Realm have gone out of scope, which can cause problems.

The recommended way to handle a logout situation is to stop using the old Realm and make a note to delete it (perhaps in `NSUserDefaults`, or in a separate administrative Realm). Upon subsequent app launches (but *before opening any Realms*), your app would look and see if there were any Realms marked for deletion, and then delete their database and support files from disk.